# php reverse concatenation operator like .=

Tags: php

Don't think this exists but just want to make sure.

Is there a reverse for the .= operator in php.

example:

```
[$x .= $y] === [$x = $x.$y]
```

looking for:

```
[$x ? $y] === [$x = $y.$x]
```

Comment: Simple answer, "no", there is no pre-concatenation operator

Comment: Thanks, didn't think so. Just thought I would make sure since there has been some large changes in the last couple of PHP releases.

Comment: Not sure what your seconds example is supposed to actually mean.

Comment: @CBroe: `.=` appends to a string. OP wants to prepend to a string and is asking if there's an operator like `.=` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No, there isn't.

The [PHP manual documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) only lists two operators:

> There are two string operators. The first is the concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments. The second is the concatenating assignment operator ('.='), which appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the left side.

When you want to prepend to a string, just do `$str = $add . $str`. There is no need for a "special operator" here. If you use it frequently and don't want to retype it every time, you can create a function like this:

```
function prepend($text, $add) {
   return $add . $text;
}
```

But, as you can probably guess, it's pointess.

Comment: Thanks, it is strange that this does not exist. The lack of this operator causes some unnecessary bloating of code in some cases.

Comment: I i am used to have a String Object, which has such a Method and Returns self: `$mystring->append('bar')->prepend('foo')->toupper();` so wrapping mustn't be pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Amal Murali's answer gave me an idea.

```
function p(&$x,$y){
    $x = $y.$x;
    return $x;
}
```

Now instead of having to type out;

```
$var1 = $var2 . $var1;
```

You can just do:

```
p($var1, $var2);
```

If you send the first variable as reference it does clean the code a bit.

**Variables:**

```
$var = ' world';
$var2 = 'Hello';
```

**Usage**

```
echo p($var, $var2);
```

or

```
p($var, $var2);
echo $var;
```

**is now equal to:**

```
$var = $var2 . $var1;
echo $var;
```